# PHP variable loses its value

Tags: php, variables, object

I have a really serious problem that I have not seen before.

On a website we are using opensource SQC eshop, PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 and there is some kind of problem with variable memory *I think*.

SQC uses notORM and here the problem starts with fatal error "Call to function on non object notORMResult" .

So I dug deeper and found the constructor of `NotORM` that looks like this:

```
function __construct(PDO $connection, NotORM_Structure $structure = null,NotORM_Cache $cache = null) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
    if($_GET['test']){
        var_dump($structure);
    }
    if (!isset($structure)) {
        $structure = new NotORM_Structure_Convention;
    }
    if($_GET['test']){
        var_dump($structure);
    }
    $this->structure = $structure;
    if($_GET['test']){
        var_dump($this->structure);
        exit("1");
    }
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

And so the output is NULL because the constructor gets no structure param so we create an object.  Second output is the object. Then we set the object to attribute and then the THIRD OUTPUT IS NULL

How is this even possible? The site was running for about year and half and no problems till yesterday. I didn't made yet any updates to php and this thing really freaks me out 'cause it's not a constant problem. It just happens sometimes after 2 hours, sometimes after 2 mins and I have really no idea why is this happening.

And btw ... this is just the start it happens across the whole script. Object attributes are set but when you want to read them they give you NULL. There is also second website running on the same server, same php same configuration without problem.

Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: is there "magic method" `__set` used?

Comment: Check your server logs for what happened 'yesterday'. I suspect something happened to change the environment for the software in some way. Your assumption that 'nothing changed' may need to be verified before checking the code.

Comment: well i checked all logs, syslog , apache logs and really i dont think there can be any change becuz that server is under my "administration", magic method set is not used and i think it should not be called unless you access attributes outside class.

Comment: if it worked yesterday and doesn't work today, that generally means something about your environment changed. Are you connecting to or pulling libraries remotely from somewhere? Has the HTML for the form been changed?